# Time interval for if/else - how to?

Tags: android, time

I have a code for current time:

```
String date = DateFormat.format("HH:mm", new Date().getTime().toString);
```

How can I make **if/else with interval** for this time +/- 15 minutes? For example:

```
if (date @@@ +/- 15 minutes @@@) {
code
} else {
code
}
```

Comment: you can use 2 conditions connected with `&&`, like `datePlus15min.after(yourDate) && dateMinus15min.before(yourDate)`

Comment: can you pls write example? what is the command .after?

Comment: that's not a command, that is a method of `Date` class

Comment: Why would you convert the current date to a string? It is much easier to handle it as a date.

Comment: If I not convert to String, can I make interval?

Comment: Thanx, before and after helped me.